# Date & time save in JSON file

Tags: json, angularjs

What is the best way for saving the Date & Time in a JSON file with Angularjs.

```
$scope.attachedFile.push({
    "fileNameGUID": GUID() + "." + $scope.fileContent.FileName.split('.').pop(),
    "fileTitle": $scope.currentFileTitle,
    "fileSize": $scope.fileContent.Size,
    "fileName": $scope.fileContent.FileName,
    "fileContent": $scope.fileContent.Content
 });
```

Thanks for shairing

Comment: What have you tried? I don't think there's a "best way", it depends on your requirements. You could save it in milliseconds or as a string.

Comment: I want save it as string.
I want when i upload my file, it shows the Upload date & time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a timestamp as shown below using the Date object. `new Date()` will set the current time and data as a sting.

```
$scope.attachedFile.push({
    "fileNameGUID": GUID() + "." + $scope.fileContent.FileName.split('.').pop(),
    "fileTitle": $scope.currentFileTitle,
    "fileSize": $scope.fileContent.Size,
    "fileName": $scope.fileContent.FileName,
    "fileContent": $scope.fileContent.Content,
    // Add this line
    "fileUploadTimestamp": new Date() // or new Date().getTime() for milliseconds
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no *better* or *worse* way in my opinion, just something that meet your requirements.

I personally prefer using **unix timestamp** to avoid hard conversion from string to native date objects in server/client communication. However many AngularJS modules like angular-bootstrap and its datepicker are prepared for using [JavaScript native Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

So if you are not planning to frequently send that data via http request, maybe **Date object** would be the best choice, since you already have a nice API with methods for i18n, conversion...

If you feel like having to do a lot of date operations, maybe you can also consider using a time and date library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), which is really powerful.